# Android NDK build: cannot locate symbol" _ZNSsD1Ev"

Tags: android, linker, android-ndk, loader

I am building a source code using Android Standalone Tool chain (that was created using Make_standalone_toolchain.sh). 
I am successfully able to compile all the required shared objects.  On loading the shared objects using System.LoadLibrary API in Java app, I get the following loader error:

failed: Cannot load library: soinfo_relocate(linker.cpp:975): cannot locate symbol "_ZNSsD1Ev" referenced by

The shared object has C++ code.

Has anyone observed such an issue where the linker is successfull, but loader fails to locate a symbol during loading of the .so.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Unmangling via c++filt: `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()`

Comment: I have had a similar experience with the symbol being "_ZN6icu_4813UnicodeStringC1Ev".  It seems like there is a similar pattern but I have yet to track down the cause.

Comment: did you find solution to this?